# Why can't I use unicode string literals directly in my code

Tags: java, string, unicode, comparison

I am using Windows XP with support for my language Urdu. IDE is JCreator. The problem that I am facing is that for my project it would be far easy if I'm able to use Urdu text directly in my code but unfortunately it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

//urWord is any word in the method argument

```
    String s = "\u0628\u0627\u067e";
    String trial = "باپ";

    int comparison = s.compareTo(urWord);
    System.out.println (urWord);
    System.out.println (comparison);

    //works perfectly
    if(s.equals(urWord)){

        System.out.println ("Strings are equal");
    }

    //does not work
    if(s.equals(trial)){

        System.out.println ("Strings are equal");
    }
```

Comment: Your code works for me, s equals trial and if I pass the Urdu word to `urWord` via a command-line argument, it does work as well. Everything is equal. So you most likely have an encoding issue with your IDE, operating system or wherever you get `urWord` from.

Comment: how about use utf-8 literals, in a source code already encoded in utf-8? http://utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 1):

If your files are encoded with any flavor of Unicode-specified encoding, this should work. So check your IDE's configuration on the encoding used for Java source code.